# Форматирование чисел. Как указать динамичную точность дробной части, в зависимости от количества знаков?

Tags: c#, .net-6

Требуется отобразить число с разделителем " " в разрядах, знак дробной части брать от культуры, а цифры в дробной части нужно отображать до 2х знаков И скрывать нули

Для форматирования пользователя документацией https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Выбрал для задачи формат "N", но он не убирает лишние нули в конце. Если указать "N2", то будет округлять до 2х знаков и будет отображать `12 345,50`
Как можно избавиться от лишних нулей в конце?

```
Console.WriteLine(BalanceFormat(12345.56m, "ru"));
Console.WriteLine(BalanceFormat(12345.5m, "ru"));
Console.WriteLine(BalanceFormat(12345m, "ru"));
Console.WriteLine(BalanceFormat(12345.56m, "en"));

string BalanceFormat(decimal price, string locale)
{
    var cultureFormat = new CultureInfo(locale)
        { NumberFormat = { NumberGroupSeparator = "\u00A0" } };
    return price.ToString("N", cultureFormat);
}
```

Ожидание:

```
12 345,56
12 345,5
12 345
12 345.56
```

Результат:

```
12 345,560
12 345,500
12 345,000
12 345.560
```

Comment: `"0.##"` в качестве формата

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov тогда не сработает разделитель между разрядами: будет `12345,5` вместо `12 345,5`

Comment: `"#,0.##"` - black magic

Comment: [The "," custom specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-2) - запятая указывает разбивать число на группы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На вопрос ответил @AlexanderPetrov , использование формата `"#,0.##"` вместо `"N"`

```
Console.WriteLine(BalanceFormat(12345.56m, "ru"));
Console.WriteLine(BalanceFormat(12345.5m, "ru"));
Console.WriteLine(BalanceFormat(12345m, "ru"));
Console.WriteLine(BalanceFormat(12345.56m, "en"));

string BalanceFormat(decimal price, string locale)
{
    var cultureFormat = new CultureInfo(locale)
        { NumberFormat = { NumberGroupSeparator = "\u00A0" } };
    return price.ToString("#,0.##", cultureFormat);
}
```

Результат:

```
12 345,56
12 345,5
12 345
12 345.56
```